# Deleting List Entries while iterating through a List

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
final List<ItemDto> itemDtos = result.getResults();
List<String> deleteItemIds = new ArrayList<String>();

// remove items which have been deleted on the server
for(ItemDto itemDto : itemDtos) {
  if (itemDto.getIsRemoved()) {
    deleteItemIds.add(itemDto.getId());
    itemDtos.remove(itemDto);  //  TODO not sure if this works here
  }
}
```

I iterate over the itemDtos and remove an ItemDto at the last operation in the for loop. I think that this works if I do not need something like `itemDtos.indexOf(o)`inside the loop.

**Is the code I did correctly working?**

Edit: Here is a second variant:

```
List<ItemDto> itemDtos = result.getResults();
List<ItemDto> tmpList = itemDtos;
List<String> deleteItemIds = new ArrayList<String>();

// remove items which have been deleted on the server
for(ItemDto itemDto : tmpList) {
  if (itemDto.getIsRemoved()) {
    deleteItemIds.add(itemDto.getId());
    itemDtos.remove(itemDto);  //  TODO not sure if this works here
  }
}
```

**Is the second variant better?**

Comment: This throws concurrent item modification exception right?

Comment: to remove items from a list while iterating through it you should use an iterator and use the iterator.remove method

Comment: Perhaps ... why don't you tell us? Write a unit test and see whether it works the way you expect it to. ;)

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To safely remove elements from a list you should use the `Iterator` of the list like this:

```
for (Iterator<ItemDto> iterator = itemDtos.iterator(); iterator.hasNext()) {
    ItemDto itemDto = iterator.next();
    if (itemDto.getIsRemoved()) {
        deleteItemIds.add(itemDto.getId());
        iterator.remove(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it work with the second variant I posted in my edit?

Comment: You still doesn't use Iterator in the second variant. To safely remove items you have to use Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove object from a list when you perform a loop on this last. But you can use the iterators.

```
    Iterator<ItemDto> iterator = arrayList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ItemDto item = iterator.next();
        //Do your job
        iterator.remove();
    }
```

A second solution could be to loop a first time to find all the elements to delete, store them within a list, and then remove them from the first list thank to List.removeAll.

Comment: Would it work with the second variant I posted in my edit?